# Permission denied for Dockerfile while using Custom Build Environment Plugin

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I am using Custom Builds Environment Plugin (1.6.5) and configured my Dockerfile to build it inside the Jenkins slave container.

[image]

Issue - I am able to build the image from Dockerfile but the build fails with the below error.

```
+ /path/to/jenkins-slave/workspace/Dockerfile
/tmp/hudson5103005593128970928.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson5103005593128970928.sh: /path/to/jenkins-slave/workspace/Dockerfile: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Stopping Docker container after build completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Dockerfile has - `FROM php:5.6.11-apache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assure, that the docker repository (the directory where the Dockerfile is and all its subfolder / files), can be read/write by the user which runs the slave.jar.

1. Get the user which runs the slave.jar. On the the host where the slave runs: `ps -elf | grep slave.jar`
2. Give this user access to the docker repository: `chown -R <user>:<group> /path/to/jenkins-slave/workspace/`